# Average values in two Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given two ndarrays

```
old_set = [[0, 1], [4, 5]]
new_set = [[2, 7], [0, 1]]
```

I'm looking to get the mean of the respective values between the two arrays so that the data ends up something like:

```
end_data = [[1, 4], [2, 3]]
```

basically it would apply something like

```
for i in len(old_set):
    end_data[i] = (old_set[i]+new_set[i])/2
```

But I'm unsure what syntax to use.. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: That will not work because you have nested arrays.

Comment: Hey Forde the answer below the answer you marked is a way better one. Would you mind marking that one instead?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can create a 3D array containing your 2D arrays to be averaged, then average along `axis=0` using `np.mean` or `np.average` (the latter allows for weighted averages):

```
np.mean( np.array([ old_set, new_set ]), axis=0 )
```

This averaging scheme can be applied to any `(n)`-dimensional array, because the created `(n+1)`-dimensional array will always contain the original arrays to be averaged along its `axis=0`.

Comment: Excellent use of numpy functions.

Comment: I really like this option. Specially, if you want to ignore nan: `np.nanmean( np.array([ old_set, new_set ]), axis=0 )`

Comment: You can also extend this to an arbitrary number of arrays using `np.mean( np.array([ i for i in bigArr]), axis=0 )` where `bigArr` is composed of many one 1D arrays to average.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it supports an arbitrary number of arrays, too.

Answer (score 52):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> old_set = [[0, 1], [4, 5]]
>>> new_set = [[2, 7], [0, 1]]
>>> (np.array(old_set) + np.array(new_set)) / 2.0
array([[1., 4.],
       [2., 3.]])
```

Comment: Unless you are using Python 3 or you use `from __future__ import division`, you should divide by 2.0 to ensure that you use true division and not integer division.

Comment: obviously, if both are already np.arrays, `(old_set + new_set) / 2` will suffice. just ask `type(old_set),type(new_set)` to remind yourself what you are dealing with.

Comment: @Gabriel123, According to the code in question, they are lists, unlike OP mentioned. ;)

Answer (score 5):

### Using `numpy.average`

Also [`numpy.average`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) can be used with the same syntax:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([np.arange(0,9).reshape(3,3),np.arange(9,18).reshape(3,3)])
averaged_array = np.average(a,axis=0)
```

The advantage of numpy.average compared to [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html#numpy.mean) is the possibility to use also the weights parameter as an array of the same shape:

```
weighta = np.empty((3,3))    
weightb = np.empty((3,3))       
weights = np.array([weighta.fill(0.5),weightb.fill(0.8) ])
np.average(a,axis=0,weights=weights)
```

If you use masked arrays consider also using [`numpy.ma.average`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.average.html#numpy.ma.average) because [`numpy.average` don't deal with them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38783757/2132157).

Comment: Good tip with the `numpy.average` and weighting factors

Answer (score 0):

As previously said, your solution does not work because of the nested lists (2D matrix). Staying away from numpy methods, and if you want to use nested for-loops, you can try something like:

```
old_set = [[0, 1], [4, 5]]
new_set = [[2, 7], [0, 1]]

ave_set = []
for i in range(len(old_set)):
    row = []
    for j in range(len(old_set[0])):
        row.append( ( old_set[i][j] + new_set[i][j] ) / 2 )
    ave_set.append(row)
print(ave_set) # returns [[1, 4], [2, 3]]
```