# How to find the average of each element in two different lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, average

These are my arrays

```
image =  [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
           ]
image1 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0] 
           ]
```

I want to get the average of each element from the different arrays and make a list of new averages, please help

This is what I have done so far:
[image]

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far - see [ask] and [mre].

Comment: ok added the code

Comment: Please post text instead of images whenever possible.

Comment: Do **not** post images. Post all code as formatted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
ans = (np.array(image) + np.array(image1))/2.0
ans = ans.tolist()
```

but it seems to be a duplicate question
[Average values in two Numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461623/average-values-in-two-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Numpy ninja code.

```py
import numpy as np
image =  [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
           ]
image1 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0] 
           ]
images = [image,image1]
np.array(images).mean(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, your code would have worked as following:

```py
imagi = []
for x, y in zip(img, img1):
    z = (x + y) / 2
    imagi.append(z)
```